# Wix: Executing installed exe as a first action on Uninstall

Tags: wix, windows-installer

In my msi, I have to call the installed exe file with some parameters, as a very first action of uninstall. Here is the code:

```
<CustomAction Id="UnRegisterOnUninstallApplication"
              Execute="immediate"
              FileKey="MyProgram.exe" ExeCommand="/unregister"  Return="asyncNoWait" />

<InstallExecuteSequence>
  <RemoveExistingProducts After="InstallInitialize"/>
  <Custom Action="UnRegisterOnUninstallApplication"  Before="UnpublishComponents" >Installed AND NOT UPGRADINGPRODUCTCODE</Custom>
</InstallExecuteSequence>
```

Although, it is scheduled Before UnpublishComponents, but issue is, at some computers, custom action is called during or after dependency dlls are uninstalled and so MyProgram.exe crashes here.
This is something seems unpredictable...

Can anyone please guide, if I'm missing something or doing something wrong???
Thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 2):

There are several things incorrect here:

1. The design issue is that you shouldn't be running code to register or unregister. The recommended way is to capture the registry entries and add them as registry entries in the same component as that binary. Then it all just works.
2. Your custom action is asyncNoWait, and that means the uninstall continues while the program runs. If it takes a long time for some reason, or simply doesn't get enough of the processor, then yes, files may have been removed by the time it runs.
3. It's an immediate custom action, so it can run and start unregistering as the uninstall proceeds. However if the uninstall fails and rolls back the deleted registration will not be restored, so you'll end up with a broken product still installed, those registration entries will stay removed. It should be a deferred custom action and return = ignore or check, depending on whether you care if the program fails.

Answer (score 0):

I might schedule the action before 'RemoveFiles' so that no dependent dlls have been removed before your custom action gets to run.